# Pass property from InSequence to faultSequence

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I need to pass a property from my InSequence to my faultSequence, for logging purposes.

With the standard scopes like default or axis2 it doesn't work , i get null value in the defaultSequence.

Any idea ?
Tks
Nicolas

Comment: It should work, could you share your proxy configuration ?

Answer (score 0):

Define a Sequence for handling the errors those are relevant to that particular inSequence.

eg: Create a sequence named "CustomFaultSequence" and code your Error handling logic inside that sequence.

```
<sequence xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="CustomFaultSequence">
   <log level="custom">
      <property xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" 
          xmlns:ns3="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" 
          name="my-property value is" 
          expression="get-property('my-property')"></property>
   </log>
</sequence>
```

Then, introduce the above Sequence to the relevant inSequence, with the use of '`onError`' attribute.

eg:

```
<inSequence onError="CustomFaultSequence">
    <property name="my-property"
              value="Stack Overflow"
              scope="default"
              type="STRING"/>
           ......{your code}.....
         <send/>
 </inSequence>
```

When an error occurs, you will definitely get an output like,

```
... INFO - LogMediator my-property value is = Stack Overflow
```

printed on your server console.

Thanks.